# Trouble with errors failing to reject with bluebird. Resolves just fine. Errors crash the app it seems

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise, bluebird

I'm working on an [app](https://github.com/dkran/email-thinky-test) using [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap), and I've been having a real hard time with errors being handled, or the lack thereof. I have the following functions:

```
////imap-helpers.js
function searchBox(searchTerm, bodies){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    searchTerm = searchTerm || ['ALL']
    bodies = bodies || ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO CC BCC SUBJECT)','TEXT']
    imap.search(searchTerm, function(err, results){
      if (err) reject(err)
      var messages = [], newMessage = {}, count=0;
      var f = imap.fetch(results, {
        bodies: bodies,
        struct: true
      });

      f.on('message', function(msg) {
        newMessage = {}

        msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
          //When we get a message, append the header to header, text to body.
          stream.on('data', function(chunk){
            if (info.which !== 'TEXT')
              newMessage.rawHeader += chunk.toString('utf8')
            else
              newMessage.body += chunk.toString('utf8')
          })

          //When stream is done, strip the unparsable characters at the beginning before parsing.
          //NOTE: I'm not actually sure what these unparseable characters actually are
          //but this all works kosher.
          stream.once('end', function() {
            if (info.which !== 'TEXT'){
              newMessage.rawHeader = newMessage.rawHeader.replace(/^undefined/, '')
              newMessage.header = Imap.parseHeader(newMessage.rawHeader)
            }
            if(newMessage.body)
              newMessage.body = newMessage.body.replace(/^undefined/, '')
          })
        })

        msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
          newMessage.attrs = attrs
        })

        msg.once('end', function() {
          messages[count] = _.omit(newMessage, 'rawHeader')
          count++
        })

      })

      f.on('error', function(e){
        reject(e)
      })

      f.once('end', function(){
        resolve(messages)
      })

    })
  })
}

exports.getByUID = function(boxName, uid){
  boxName = boxName || 'INBOX'
  var searchTerm = ['ALL',['UID',uid]]
  return imap.openBoxAsync(boxName, false).then(function(){
    return searchBox(searchTerm, ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO CC BCC SUBJECT)']).then(function(messages){
      return messages
    }).catch(function(e){
      throw e
    })
  }).catch(function(e){
    return e
  })
}
```

and then I could just call it in a file.

```
//imap-controller.js - severely amended version
  getOne: function(req, res){
    methods.getByUID('INBOX',req.params.uid).then(function(response){
      res.json(response)
    }).catch(function(e){
      res.json({error: e.message})
    })
  }
```

but the problem is I have no luck returning errors to the controller.  it just constantly breaks the program with

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Nothing to fetch
    at Connection._fetch (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:778:11)
    at Connection.fetch (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:771:15)
    at Connection.tryCatcher (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at Connection.ret [as fetchAsync] (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promisify.js:163:12), <anonymous>:15:23)
    at /Users/dkranec/github/imap/app.js:34:12
    at tryCatcher (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:503:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:577:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:693:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/dkranec/github/imap/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:371:17)
```

Please see a related reddit post I made on this topic here with a small version of this function as an app I made also having issues if you think you can help with that [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/3h2gtt/help_needed_with_promises_and_nodeimap_cant/). Basically another version of the same issue, but catching errors but not putting out the imap.fetch emitter on successes.  I can't win!

Comment: well, at least `if (err) reject(err)` should be `if (err) { reject(err); return; }`

Comment: What is `imap.openBoxAsync`? Is this a function that you wrote? If so, you need to show it.

Comment: Are you sure that `var newMessage ...` is in the correct scope? As written every `f.on('message' ...` will cause the previous `newMessage` to be overwritten and the streams will only ever contribute their chunks to the last `newMessage` created - which is at least potentially the wrong one! I would have thought that `var newMessage ...` should be in the `f.on('message' ...` scope.

Comment: You can avoid the need to replace "undefined" by initializing `newMessage` properly - `var newMessage = { body:'', rawHeader:''}`.

Comment: I don't want to create a new variable on every new event.  I want to create it once and empty it on every new event @Roamer-1888. @Yuri The `imap.openBoxAsync` is just a `bluebird` [promisified](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) version of the `imap.openBox`.  No real great shakes there.

Comment: @dkran, so is this an event based parser where the various events are dispatched by a single synchronous process?

Answer (score 0):

In `searchBox()` the main thing to do is to `return;` after `reject(err);`, as  @KirillSlatin says in comment above.

Here's the whole function with some further (untested) suggestions :

```
function searchBox(searchTerm, bodies) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        searchTerm = searchTerm || ['ALL'];
        imap.search(searchTerm, function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 
            }
            var messages = [],
                f = imap.fetch(results, {
                    bodies: bodies || ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO CC BCC SUBJECT)','TEXT'],
                    struct: true
                });
            f.on('message', function(msg) {
                var rawHeader = '',
                    newMessage = { body: '' };
                msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
                    stream.on('data', function(chunk) { ((info.which == 'TEXT') ? newMessage.body : rawHeader) += chunk.toString('utf8') });
                    // stream.once('end', function() { });//no point doing anything here providing msg.once('end') fires later.
                });
                msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) { newMessage.attrs = attrs; });
                msg.once('end', function() {
                    newMessage.header = rawHeader.length ? Imap.parseHeader(rawHeader) : '';
                    newMessage.attrs = newMessage.attrs || [];//safety
                    messages.push(newMessage);
                });
            });
            f.on('error', reject);
            f.once('end', function() { resolve(messages); });
        });
    });
}
```

With `newMessage` declared inside the `f.on('message')` handler, there's  no chance of messages cross-talking when the nested events occur, regardless of the nature of event dispatch - synchronous or asynchronous.

And `.getByUID()` will pass on any errors without needing to catch/rethrow :

```
exports.getByUID = function(boxName, uid) {
    return imap.openBoxAsync(boxName || 'INBOX', false).then(function() {
        return searchBox(['ALL', ['UID', uid]], ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO CC BCC SUBJECT)']);
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I found out my issue here is the way in which the `imap.fetch()` function is written.  It's not written to handle a callback style.  it either returns an event emitter via `return new EventEmitter()`, or fails entirely via `throw new Error()`. I don't think those errors will be handled gracefully no matter what by bluebird.  I might have to write a custom promisification handler for that function.

Comment: I tried a `try{var f = imap.fetch()...} catch(e){ console.log(e); reject(e); return; } that logs the error properly without crashing my app, but doesn't reject... why?

Comment: Frustrating that `imap.fetch()` doesn't follow the same node pattern as `imap.search()`. 

The documentation gives no indication that some/any `imap.fetch()` errors won't give rise to an emmitted 'error' event. 

Thought: All examples in the documentation use `.once('error' ...)` not `.on('error' ...)`.

Comment: Yes but still why doesnt my try / catch block reject properly if it console.logs properly

Comment: Like you, I'd like to know.

Comment: You might try chaining .catch(), .error() or .done() to the `new Promise()`?

Comment: believe it or not, shortening `getByUid` to the function without then/catch fixed it.  The try / catch block seems to be unavoidable.  The `return` after the `reject(e)` or `resolve(e)` is not required it seems?